# Lauching Intent from <a href> link in WebView works with API 19 but not with API 17

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am trying tu use `<a href="intent:#Intent;...">` links from web pages embedded in the APK of my application to interact with it. These pages are displayed with a `WebView`.

This works fine with my API 19 device and with my API 19 emulator, but not with my API 17 emulators. These ones make the `WebView` to display the dreaded "WEBPAGE NOT AVAILABLE" message instead of lauching the `Intent` embedded in the `a` link:

[image]

I don't manage to determine why the behaviour differs between API 19 and API 17:

- is this tied to the API version? (but some SO posts that look older than API 19 refer to such `Intent` links)
- does this works "by accident" on my API 19 devices (Incorrect `Intent` HTML link or `<intent-filter>`? I did researches that describe this as working though)
- or did I miss anything, maybe in the permissions?

The involved code follows:

**Manifest**:

```
[...]

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

[...]

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MyAppMain"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- "THIS FILTER IS THE RELEVANT ONE: IT CATCHES INTENTS SENT FROM THE WEBVIEW" -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.myapp.CALL_FROM_LINK" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

 [...]

</application>
```

**Involved Activity**:

```
public class MyAppMain extends Activity { 
    [...]

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        // The actual UI is HTML code displayed in a WebView
        final WebView webview = new WebView(this);

        try {
            // Determines the page to load. "page1.html" by default if no extra available.
            final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            final String asset = extras != null ? extras.getString("page") : "page1.html";
            final InputStream is = getAssets().open(asset, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);

            // The line below does just put the content of the stream in a String
            final String html = StreamHelper.InputStreamToString(is); 

            // Loads the page into the WebView.          
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // For now :)
        }  

        setContentView(webview); 
    } 

    [...]
}
```

**HTML link that lauches the `Intent`**:

```
<a href="intent:#Intent;action=com.example.myapp.CALL_FROM_LINK;S.page=page2.html;end">Other content</a>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ??

Comment: @miladsalimi I didn't actually, so I worked around with a JS/backend binding